# Heroku kind of hosting for simple HTML/JS applications

Tags: javascript, html, heroku, hosting

I love using **Heroku**. I love the simplicity of doing `git push` into the server and have the Ruby on Rails app up and running.

I am doing a simple HTML/JS application and I am wondering if there is any **free** hosting that allows this simplicity of pushing the app just by doing `git push`.

Answer (score 12):

These should answer your question:

1. [Static Sites on Heroku Cedar](http://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/static-sites-on-heroku-cedar)

   > First, lets turn your site into a PHP "application":
   >
   > `$ touch index.php`
   >
   > Next, we can fully disable Apache's PHP engine:
   >
   > `$ echo 'php_flag engine off' > .htaccess`
   >
   > When you push this up, you'll have a bare Apache instance serving up the contents of your site to the world. Best yet, you can do all of the stupid .htaccess tricks that you could on on any traditional shared hosting platform.
2. [heroku-static-site](https://github.com/jamiew/heroku-static-site)

   > A simple ruby + rack application for serving a basic static website

You might also want to check out [github pages](http://pages.github.com) which provides free static hosting that can be updated with just a `git push`. The advantage of github pages over Heroku is that there won't be any [Dyno Idling](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#dyno-idling).

Comment: The first link seems to 404 but the snippet you posted pretty much sums it up.

Comment: @dperjar - link fixed  :o)